# Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/keys' - Heroku Node environment

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I keep getting this error when deploying my Node and Mean app to Heroku. The app seems to work normally when I run it locally but does not like it when I push it to Heroku.

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/keys'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous>     (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/internal/iterator.js:16:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "utdknow",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "aws-sdk": "^2.6.12",
  "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
  "crypto-js": "^3.1.8",
  "ejs": "^2.3.4",
  "express": "^4.13.3",
  "lodash": "^4.17.3",
  "lodash.keys": "^4.2.0",
  "moment": "^2.17.0",
  "mongoose": "^4.2.5",
  "ng-file-upload": "^12.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try requiring `lodash.keys`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like modules are not correctly installed. Try cleaning cache and deploy your app to re-install all dependencies:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo

`heroku plugins:install heroku-repo`

`heroku repo:purge_cache --app appname`